# when to use mutex

Tags: c++, mutex

Here is the thing: there is a float array `float bucket[5]` and 2 threads, say thread1 and thread2.

Thread1 is in charge of tanking up the `bucket`, assigning each element in `bucket` a random number. When the bucket is tanked up, thread2 will access `bucket` and read its elements.

Here is how I do the job:

```
float bucket[5];
pthread_mutex_t mu = PTHREAD_MUTEX_INITIALIZER;
pthread_t thread1, thread2;

void* thread_1_proc(void*);  //thread1's startup routine, tank up the bucket 
void* thread_2_proc(void*);  //thread2's startup routine, read the bucket 

int main()
{
    pthread_create(&thread1, NULL, thread_1_proc, NULL);
    pthread_create(&thread2, NULL, thread_2_proc, NULL);
    pthread_join(thread1);
    pthread_join(thread2);
}
```

Below is my implementation for thread_x_proc:

```
void* thread_1_proc(void*)
{
    while(1) { //make it work forever
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mu);  //lock the mutex, right?

        cout << "tanking\n";
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            bucket[i] = rand();  //actually, rand() returns int, doesn't matter

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mu); //bucket tanked, unlock the mutex, right?

        //sleep(1); /* this line is commented */
    }
}

void* thread_2_proc(void*)
{
    while(1) { 
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mu);

        cout << "reading\n";
        for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
            cout << bucket[i] << " ";  //read each element in the bucket

        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mu); //reading done, unlock the mutex, right?

        //sleep(1); /* this line is commented */
    }
}
```

**Question**

Is my implementation right? Cuz the output is not as what I expected.

```
...
reading
5.09434e+08 6.58441e+08 1.2288e+08 8.16198e+07 4.66482e+07 7.08736e+08 1.33455e+09 
reading
5.09434e+08 6.58441e+08 1.2288e+08 8.16198e+07 4.66482e+07 7.08736e+08 1.33455e+09 
reading
5.09434e+08 6.58441e+08 1.2288e+08 8.16198e+07 4.66482e+07 7.08736e+08 1.33455e+09 
reading
tanking
tanking
tanking
tanking
...
```

**But** if I uncomment the `sleep(1);` in each thread_x_proc function, the output is right, `tanking` and `reading` follow each other, like this:

```
...
tanking
reading
1.80429e+09 8.46931e+08 1.68169e+09 1.71464e+09 1.95775e+09 4.24238e+08 7.19885e+08 
tanking
reading
1.64976e+09 5.96517e+08 1.18964e+09 1.0252e+09 1.35049e+09 7.83369e+08 1.10252e+09 
tanking
reading
2.0449e+09 1.96751e+09 1.36518e+09 1.54038e+09 3.04089e+08 1.30346e+09 3.50052e+07
...
```

Why? Should I use `sleep()` when using `mutex`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your code is **technically** correct, but it does not make a lot of sense, and it does not do what you assume.

What your code *does* is, it updates a section of data atomically, and reads from that section, atomically. However, you don't know in which order this happens, nor how often the data is written to before being read (or if at all!).

What you probably *wanted* is generate exactly one sequence of numbers in one thread every time and read exactly one new sequence each time in the other thread. For this, you would use either have to use an additional semaphore or better a single-producer-single-consumer queue.

In general the answer to "when should I use a mutex" is "never, if you can help it". Threads should send messages, not share state. This makes a mutex most of the time unnecessary, and offers parallelism (which is the main incentive for using threads in the first place).

The mutex makes your threads run lockstep, so you could as well just run in a single thread.

Comment: It's Not technically correct as its behaviour is undefined (it may tank twice in a row for example which it "shouldn't").

Comment: I would say answer to "when to use mutexes?" is "only when you need to protect agains priority inversion". I think in all other cases there are better ways to apprach the problem.

Comment: @elmo: although certain people argue against semaphores in favour of condition variables as being "easier to use". I don't entirely agree, but that's why Boost has no intra-process semaphore (and I assume the reasoning was the same for C++11, which also has no semaphore). So the other reason to use a mutex is "because it's necessary for the condition variable" :-)

Comment: @SteveJessop: In the statement above I assumed we have access to all three basic synchronization utitlites: mutexes, cond variables and semaphores. If you lack any of those then it is not really matter of choice... (I personally don't really like cond variables for semi-active waiting, but one might argue in most applications this doesn't impact the preformence in a noticable way).

Comment: @elmo: I think all I'm really pointing out is that those certain people wouldn't use a semaphore even if they did have one available. They use a mutex+condvar instead. And I guess they'd use it only to implement a thread-safe producer-consumer-style messaging thingummy, then write all their multi-threaded code as streaming units. Like you say, a semaphore might be faster, or for single-reader-single-writer you can go lockless with relative ease (to other lockless queues). Provided you stick to the streaming model it's not much harder to get the queue right, and the rest of the code is the same

Answer (score 2):

There is no implied order in which threads will get to run. This means **you shall not expect any order**. What's more it is possible to get on thread running over and over without letting the other to run. This is implementation specific and should be assumed random.

The case you presented falls much rather for a semaphor which is "posted" with each element added.

However if it has always to be like:

- write 5 elements
- read 5 elements

you should have two mutexes:

- one that blocks producer until the consumer finished
- one that blocks consumer until the producer finished

So the code should look something like that:

```
Producer:
    while(true){
        lock( &write_mutex )
        [insert data]
        unlock( &read_mutex )
    }

Consumer:
    while(true){
        lock( &read_mutex )
        [insert data]
        unlock( &write_mutex )
    }
```

Initially `write_mutex` should be unlocked and `read_mutex` locked.

As I said your code seems to be a better case for semaphores or maybe condition variables.
Mutexes are not meant for cases such as this (which doesn't mean you can't use them, it just means there are more handy tools to solve that problem).

Answer (score 2):

You have no right to assume that just because you want your threads to run in a particular order, the implementation will figure out what you want and actually run them in that order.

Why shouldn't thread2 run before thread1? And why shouldn't each thread complete its loop several times before the other thread gets a chance to run up to the line where it acquires the mutex?

If you want execution to switch between two threads in a predictable way, then you need to use a semaphore, condition variable, or other mechanism for messaging between the two threads. `sleep` appears to result in the order you want on this occasion, but even with the sleep you haven't done enough to guarantee that they will alternate. And I have no idea why the `sleep` makes a difference to which thread gets to run first -- is that consistent across several runs?

Comment: After several tests, that is consistent, but your explanation is apparently right. Upvoted.

Comment: @Alcott: maybe your original misunderstanding was to think that `pthread_mutex_unlock` means "give the mutex to a different thread". It doesn't, it just releases the mutex so that this thread or any other can acquire it in future. Until another thread gets a chance to run, it's going to be this one, so the difference that `sleep` makes is just to let something else run. With the sleeps, the threads will get the mutex alternately provided they wake up alternately, which is likely but not guaranteed since `sleep(1)` isn't necessarily exactly 1 second every time.

Answer (score 1):

If you have two functions that should execute sequentially, i.e. F1 should finish before F2 starts, then you shouldn't be using two threads. Run F2 on the same thread as F1, after F1 returns.

Without threads, you won't need the mutex either.

Comment: well, but I want f1 to work forever, furthermore, f1 and f2 share data, right?

Comment: Neither the "forever" nor the "share data" really makes a difference: `for(;;) { f1(data); f2(data); }`. Or in OO-style: `for(;;) { object.f1(); object.f2(); }`. Still no mutex.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't really the issue here.

The sleep only lets the 'other' thread access the mutex lock (by chance, it is waiting for the lock so Probably it will have the mutex), there is no way you can be sure the first thread won't re-lock the mutex though and let the other thread access it.

Mutex is for protecting data so two threads don't :
a) write simultaneously
b) one is writing when another is reading

It is not for making threads work in a certain order (if you want that functionality, ditch the threaded approach or use a flag to tell that the 'tank' is full for example).

Comment: Without threads you just: While(true){Fill_Bucket(); Empty_Bucket();}

Answer (score 0):

By now, it should be clear, from the other answers, what are the mistakes in the original code. So, let's try to improve it:

```
/* A flag that indicates whose turn it is. */
char tanked = 0;

void* thread_1_proc(void*)
{
    while(1) { //make it work forever
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mu);  //lock the mutex
        if(!tanked) { // is it my turn?
            cout << "tanking\n";
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
                bucket[i] = rand();  //actually, rand() returns int, doesn't matter
            tanked = 1;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mu); // unlock the mutex
    }
}

void* thread_2_proc(void*)
{
    while(1) {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mu);
        if(tanked) { // is it my turn?
            cout << "reading\n";
            for(int i=0; i<5; i++)
                cout << bucket[i] << " ";  //read each element in the bucket
            tanked = 0;
        }
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mu); // unlock the mutex
    }
}
```

The code above should work as expected. However, as others have pointed out, the result would be better accomplished with one of these two other options:

- Sequentially. Since the producer and the consumer must alternate, you don't need two threads. One loop that tanks and then reads would be enough. This solution would also avoid the busy waiting that happens in the code above.
- Using semaphores. This would be the solution if the producer was able to run several times in a row, accumulating elements in a bucket (not the case in the original code, though).
  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Producer-consumer_problem#Using_semaphores

Comment: What's the point here of checking the flag outside the lock? It's formally incorrect (although it'll work on a majority of implementations, if not all), and assuming it does no harm, all it really achieves is to make you busy-loop faster because you aren't grabbing and releasing the lock.

Comment: @SteveJessop It is not formally incorrect, precisely because there is busy waiting. But I agree the double-checked locking does not improve the code here (because of the busy waiting and because there is only one producer and one consumer), so I have removed it.

Comment: It's formally incorrect because there is no guarantee that a write to `tanked` in one thread is *ever* seen by the thread that's doing `while(1) if(tanked) { anything; }`. `anything` is never executed and hence never introduces any kind of memory barrier. In practice, most architectures propagate writes anyway (via cache coherency or at worst when the thread is descheduled), but AFAIK there's no guarantee in C++11 or Posix that it will, or that the optimizer won't do something that makes it irrelevant what the hardware does.

Comment: @SteveJessop What you are saying is that multithreading with shared variables (like tanked, mu, and bucket) is formally incorrect. That's a bold statement.

Comment: I'm saying that multi-threading with shared variables, without using memory barriers, is formally incorrect.

Comment: @SteveJessop You're right. Thanks. Anyway, it should be correct in the version without double-checked locking.

Comment: @SteveJessop, **memory barriers**? what is that?